# RK3588 MIPI Panel Debugging: RK3588-MIPI-DSI LCD Power up Initialization Sequence

Tags: android, linux, arm, android-hardware, csi

1. Introduction
   [Mastering RK3588 from Beginner to Expert] Series Contents

For MIPI panels, the power on init sequence (panel-init-sequence) and power off sequence (panel-exit-sequence) are usually configured in the dts file on Rockchip platforms. This article explains how to configure these initialization sequences for the panel.

2. Environment Introduction
   Hardware: ArmSoM-W3 RK3588 dev board, MIPI-DSI panel (ArmSoM official accessory)

Software Version: OS: ArmSoM-W3 Debian11

3.Data Types
3.1 Common data type1 ：DCS Write

Note: The parameter here does not refer to the number of data bytes.

```
0x05 Command type: Single byte data (DCS Short Write, no parameters) 
​0x15 Command type: Two byte data (DCS Short Write, 1 parameter) ​ 
0x39 Command type: Multi byte data (DCS Long Write, n parameters n > 2)
```

**0x05 Command type：(DCS Short Write, no parameters)**

```
05 95 01 11
05 95 01 29
```

**0x15 Command type：(DCS Short Write, 1 parameter)**

```
15 00 02 80 77
|  |  | |  |
|  |  | |  data
|  |  | | Register Address
|  |  Payload Length
|  Delay
Command type（0x05: Single byte data  0x15:Two byte data  0x39:Multi byte data）
    
Analysis：
Data Type: 0x15 (0x15 data type - DCS Short Write, 1 parameter)

Delay: 0x00 (Delay in ms after completing sending current packet before starting next command)

Payload Length: 0x02 (Payload length is 2 bytes)

Payload: 0x80 0x77 (Payload data)
```

**0x39 command type is with multiple parameters, more than two parameters (DCS Long Write / write_LUT Command Packet)**

```
39 00 06 FF 77 01 00 00 10
39 00 03 C0 63 00
39 00 03 C1 11 02
```

3.2 Common data type 2 ：Generic Write
Note: The parameter here does not refer to the number of data bytes.

```
0x03 Command type: Single byte data  (Generic Short Write, no parameters)
0x13 Command type: Two byte data (Generic Short Write, 1 parameter)

0x23 Command type: Three byte data (Generic Short Write, 2 parameters)

0x29 Command type: Multi byte data (Generic Long Write, n parameters n > 2)
```

4. Rockchip Platform Power on Initialization Sequence Configuration
   There are panel manufacturer's MIPI panel initialization code as follows

params->dsi.vertical_sync_active=2
params->dsi.vertical_backporch=10 params->dsi.vertical_frontporch=14 params->dsi.horizontal_sync_active=24 params->dsi.horizontal_backporch=80 params->dsi.horizontal_frontporch=60 params->dsi.PLL_CLOCK=478

LCD_nReset=1; Delayms(5); LCD_nReset=0; Delayms(20);//10 LCD_nReset=1; Delayms(200);//120 ​ Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xB0,0x01); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC0,0x26); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC1,0x10); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC2,0x0E); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC3,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC4,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC5,0x23); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC6,0x11); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC7,0x22); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC8,0x20); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC9,0x1E); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xCA,0x1C); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xCB,0x0C); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xCC,0x0A); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xCD,0x08); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xCE,0x06); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xCF,0x18); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xD0,0x02); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xD1,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xD2,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xD3,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xD4,0x26); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xD5,0x0F); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xD6,0x0D); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xD7,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xD8,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xD9,0x23); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xDA,0x11); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xDB,0x21); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xDC,0x1F); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xDD,0x1D); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xDE,0x1B); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xDF,0x0B); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xE0,0x09); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xE1,0x07); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xE2,0x05); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xE3,0x17); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xE4,0x01); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xE5,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xE6,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xE7,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xB0,0x03); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xBE,0x04); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xB9,0x40); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xCC,0x88); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC8,0x0C); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC9,0x07); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xCD,0x01); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xCA,0x40); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xCE,0x1A); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xCF,0x60); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xD2,0x08); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xD3,0x08); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xDB,0x01); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xD9,0x06); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xD4,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xD5,0x01); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xD6,0x04); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xD7,0x03); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC2,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC3,0x0E); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC4,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC5,0x0E); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xDD,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xDE,0x0E); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xE6,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xE7,0x0E); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC2,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC3,0x0E); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC4,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC5,0x0E); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xDD,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xDE,0x0E); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xE6,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xE7,0x0E); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xB0,0x06); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC0,0xA5); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xD5,0x1C); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC0,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xB0,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xBD,0x30);//VCOM 37

Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xF9,0x5C); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC2,0x14); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC4,0x14); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xBF,0x15); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xC0,0x0C); ​ ​ Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xB0,0x00); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xB1,0x79); Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xBA,0x8F);// ​ DCS_Short_Write_NP(0x11); Delay(200); DCS_Short_Write_NP(0x29); Delay(50);

4.1 Analyze the MIPI Panel Initialization Code Provided by the Customer:

```
Generic_Short_Write_1P(0xBA,0x8F);
Generic_Short_Write_1P indicates: Send Generic command with 1 parameter, data byte length is 2 (Generic Short Write, 1 parameter) 0xBA: Register address 0x8F: Data 1 is 0x8F
```

Convert to MIPI panel initialization format on Rockchip DTS:****

```
13 00 02 BA 8F

Analysis:
13 indicates 0x13 data type command
00 indicates no delay
02 indicates two data bytes: 0xBA, 0x8F
BA is register address 0xBA
8F is data 0x8F
```

Analyze customer's MIPI panel initialization code:

```
 DCS_Short_Write_NP(0x11);  
 Delay(200);
 DCS_Short_Write_NP(0x29);
 Delay(50);

Analysis:
DCS_Short_Write_NP means: Only send DCS command, no parameters, data byte length is 1 (DCS Short Write, no parameters)
0x11: Data 1 is 0x11
Delay(200): Delay 200 ms
```

Convert to MIPI panel initialization format on RK DTS:

```
05 C8 01 11
05 32 01 29

Analysis:
05 indicates 0x05 data type command
C8 indicates delay of 200 in hex is 0xC8
01 indicates 1 data byte: 0x11
11 is the data: 0x11
```

4.2 Convert the Panel Vendor's Initialization Code to Rockchip Platform's Power up Sequence DTS Configuration:

```
panel-init-sequence = [
            13 00 02 B0 01
            13 00 02 C0 26
            13 00 02 C1 10
            13 00 02 C2 0E
            13 00 02 C3 00
            13 00 02 C4 00
            13 00 02 C5 23
            13 00 02 C6 11
            13 00 02 C7 22
            13 00 02 C8 20
            13 00 02 C9 1E
            13 00 02 CA 1C
            13 00 02 CB 0C
            13 00 02 CC 0A
            13 00 02 CD 08
            13 00 02 CE 06
            13 00 02 CF 18
            13 00 02 D0 02
            13 00 02 D1 00
            13 00 02 D2 00
            13 00 02 D3 00
            13 00 02 D4 26
            13 00 02 D5 0F
            13 00 02 D6 0D
            13 00 02 D7 00
            13 00 02 D8 00
            13 00 02 D9 23
            13 00 02 DA 11
            13 00 02 DB 21
            13 00 02 DC 1F
            13 00 02 DD 1D
            13 00 02 DE 1B
            13 00 02 DF 0B
            13 00 02 E0 09
            13 00 02 E1 07
            13 00 02 E2 05
            13 00 02 E3 17
            13 00 02 E4 01
            13 00 02 E5 00
            13 00 02 E6 00
            13 00 02 E7 00
            13 00 02 B0 03
            13 00 02 BE 04
            13 00 02 B9 40
            13 00 02 CC 88
            13 00 02 C8 0C
            13 00 02 C9 07
            13 00 02 CD 01
            13 00 02 CA 40
            13 00 02 CE 1A
            13 00 02 CF 60
            13 00 02 D2 08
            13 00 02 D3 08
            13 00 02 DB 01
            13 00 02 D9 06
            13 00 02 D4 00
            13 00 02 D5 01
            13 00 02 D6 04
            13 00 02 D7 03
            13 00 02 C2 00
            13 00 02 C3 0E
            13 00 02 C4 00
            13 00 02 C5 0E
            13 00 02 DD 00
            13 00 02 DE 0E
            13 00 02 E6 00
            13 00 02 E7 0E
            13 00 02 C2 00
            13 00 02 C3 0E
            13 00 02 C4 00
            13 00 02 C5 0E
            13 00 02 DD 00
            13 00 02 DE 0E
            13 00 02 E6 00
            13 00 02 E7 0E
            13 00 02 B0 06
            13 00 02 C0 A5
            13 00 02 D5 1C
            13 00 02 C0 00
            13 00 02 B0 00
            13 00 02 BD 30

            13 00 02 F9 5C
            13 00 02 C2 14
            13 00 02 C4 14
            13 00 02 BF 15
            13 00 02 C0 0C


            13 00 02 B0 00
            13 00 02 B1 79
            13 00 02 BA 8F

            05 C8 01 11
            05 32 01 29
        ];

        panel-exit-sequence = [
            05 00 01 28
            05 00 01 10
        ];
 -
```

---

ArmSoM Product Introduction： http://wiki.armsom.org/index.php/ArmSoM-w3
ArmSoM Technical Forum： http://forum.armsom.org/